# sudo apachectl start not working on OS X Yosemite

Tags: php, apache, osx-yosemite

I type in the command and i get this message

> /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Operation
>   already in progress

So on safari i load the  `http://localhost` page and it gives me the error message Safari can't  connect to the server "localhost".

I'm new to this so don't have much knowledge on this but the reason i want to log in to this is to run my php scripts and test my websites on my laptop.

Ever since the os upgrade from mavericks to yosemite i couldn't run any php scrip.

Comment: Try running `ps aux | grep [h]ttpd` to check if it's already running?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First check config syntax

Run this command:

```
apachectl configtest
```

Check this post: http://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/ (Section Apache, on yellow background you have info about OS X 10.10)

Comment: I get this error when i type the command

httpd: Syntax error on line 58 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so, 10): image not found

Comment: For example: from time machine backup? Yosemite have new apache and config are different

Comment: In case you need:  there's _original_ folder which contains unmodified version of httpd.conf

Answer (score 3):

I had to uncomment (remove the `#` character) the line "`LoadModule php5_module...`" in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to re-enable PHP after upgrading, you may have to as well.

Comment: After hours of frustration, finally got the solution from your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

run "sudo apachectl -k start", it works for me

Comment: I checked the file 
    "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist",
 and find string
    "/usr/sbin/httpd-wrapper",
 it seems werid, so I change it to 
    "/usr/sbin/httpd"
, and it works, No need to run the command above any more.

Comment: i cant edit that file even if i try to change the permission also and it denies.

Answer (score 1):

"httpd.conf" file

Option FollowSymLinks Multiviews --->>>   Options ***Indexes*** FollowSymLinks Multiviews

must be OK

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
launchctl start localhost
```